# Lubuntu 16.04 isn't properly shutting down

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown

I have lubuntu 16.04 installed on my computer. Windows is also installed.

My laptop(with lubuntu) used to shut down properly. Once I pulled the usb cable of a printer connected to the laptop while it was shutting down. From then on it wouldn't shut down properly; it just gets stuck at the lubuntu screen(with the five dots). When I hit escape a black screen shows up, with '[OK] Reached Target Shutdown.' written at the end.

The only way I can then shut down the laptop is by holding down the power button.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

*STEPS I DID TO SOLVE*

- Press CTRL + ALT + T
- In terminal type `sudo xedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
- At the bottom of the file add:

  ```
  blacklist dw_dmac
  blacklist dw_dmac_core
  ```
- Save and Quit
- Type `sudo xedit /etc/default/grub`
- In the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` erase `quiet
  splash`
- Save and Quit
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot once

I did it and the PC now can PowerOff/Reboot/Suspend and everything.

Notes: This worked for ACER E-11 with previous Windows8.1 and now with Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

*Cons: During Start or ShutDown the computer will show only console, but it'll work.*

Comment: Please do not repost answers to multiple questions.  If a question is solved by the same answer, then please mark those questions as duplicates instead.